# JFreeChart tick label cut off

Tags: jfreechart

When rendering a chart using JFreeChart, if there is a tick label near to the end of the horizontal axis the label is partially cut off at the border of the image, eg:

```
 |
 |
 +----------+------------------+-
        01 Jun 11          01 Jul     <--- missing year
```

Is there any way that I can prevent this? It is possible to add some kind of margin or similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html), the parent `ValueAxis` method [`setUpperMargin()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setUpperMargin%28double%29) may suffice.

Comment: if I want to show the date at 0 positions also. How that can be shown

Comment: Maybe `setLowerMargin()`?