# JFreeChart last X-axis label cut off

Tags: jfreechart, truncation, axis-labels

I've got a nice, pretty JFreeChart-generated Line chart, with one exception - the last value on my X axis is getting truncated, like so:

```
      |
      |
      |_________|________|__________|_________|_________|
    100 Hz    1 kHz    10 kHz    100 kHz    1 MHz    10 MH
```

(Note the z in MHz is cut off).

I've looked into the solution here:
[JFreeChart tick label cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851540/jfreechart-tick-label-cut-off)

but because I'm manually specifying the range in a `LogAxis` it appears from the JavaDoc that setting the margin has no effect.
[JavaDoc](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setUpperMargin%28double%29)

This is the code I'm using to generate my X-axis:

```
      final LogAxis domainAxis = new LogAxis(frequencyAxisLabel);
      domainAxis.setStandardTickUnits(LogAxis.createLogTickUnits(Locale.ENGLISH));
      domainAxis.setRange(100, 10000000); //100Hz to 10MHz
      domainAxis.setUpperMargin(.05);  //Has no effect
      domainAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new UnitNumberFormat(UnitValue.HERTZ));
      plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
```

If it helps, I'm also writing this to a .svg file using the following:

```
          // Get a DOMImplementation and create an XML document
      DOMImplementation domImpl = GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
      Document document = domImpl.createDocument(null, "svg", null);

      // Create an instance of the SVG Generator
      SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);
      svgGenerator.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(720, 470));

      // draw the chart in the SVG generator
      Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(10, 10, 700, 450);
      chart.draw(svgGenerator, bounds);

      // Write svg file
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("SomePath));
      Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
      svgGenerator.stream(out, true /* use css */);
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();
```

Given that the setUpperMargin() method is not going to have an effect, how would I go about making sure the label has enough space to fully print?  I'm open to rotating the tick labels as well, though I haven't figured out how to do that either, only how to rotate the axis label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found one solution that works.

I used

```
chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

obviously your mileage may vary, but this seems to work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be found here on the [jfreechart board](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16469&sid=7922bd05c2332cf164801606079f9199)

In short, add the following to your code where you generate the X-Axis :

```
plot.getDomainAxis().setMaximumCategoryLabelWidthRatio(1.0f);
```

or, for your code above;

```
domainAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelWidthRatio(1.0f);
```

This solved the problem for me using a horizontal bar chart, where long domain labels were truncated with the "..." suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

// change the margin at the top of the range axis...

NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();

rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

```
    rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.15);

    rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.15);
```