# JFreeChart: customizing BoxAndWhisker chart

Tags: java, bar-chart, jfreechart

I started using `JFreeChart` to do some plotting.
I would like my chart to look like the image below:

[image: Interval graph]

I came very close by using `BoxAndWhisker` chart:

[image: my graph]

However, there are certain things that I would still like to change. Is there a way to remove the boxes so I only have the middle line? And how can I add labels to the bars? Also for some reason the last number of the y axis (bottom right in the image) is cut off.

Here is my sample code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRendererState;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.MinMaxCategoryRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class MinMaxCategoryPlotTest extends ApplicationFrame {

    public MinMaxCategoryPlotTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(1604, "1", "PESAII");
        dataset.addValue(1704, "2", "PESAII");
        dataset.addValue(1804, "3", "PESAII");

        dataset.addValue(1512, "1", "NSGAII");
        dataset.addValue(1612, "2", "NSGAII");
        dataset.addValue(1712, "3", "NSGAII");

        dataset.addValue(1436, "1", "SPEA2");
        dataset.addValue(1536, "2", "SPEA2");
        dataset.addValue(1636, "3", "SPEA2");

        dataset.addValue(1363, "1", "IBEA");
        dataset.addValue(1463, "2", "IBEA");
        dataset.addValue(1563, "3", "IBEA");

        dataset.addValue(1186, "1", "MOEA/D");
        dataset.addValue(1286, "2", "MOEA/D");
        dataset.addValue(1386, "3", "MOEA/D");

        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("");
        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);

        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Rating");
        yAxis.setRange(1100, 2000);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0"); // Override the decimal format to get integer numbers on the axis (1.800 -> 1800)
        yAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(df);
        yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

        MyMinMaxCategoryRenderer renderer = new MyMinMaxCategoryRenderer();

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // invisible
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.black);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // invisible

        renderer.setSeriesShape(1, new Line2D.Double(0, -6, 0, 6)); //not working
        renderer.setSeriesVisible(0, false); // not working

        renderer.setMinIcon(getIcon(new Line2D.Double(0, -6, 0, 6), true, true));
        renderer.setMaxIcon(getIcon(new Line2D.Double(0, -6, 0, 6), true, true));
        renderer.setObjectIcon(getIcon(new Line2D.Double(0, -4, 0, 4), true, true));

        final CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
        plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);

        final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
            title,
            new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 16),
            plot,
            false
        );

        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 400));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(10, 10, 10, 10)); // Fix: tick label cut off

    }

    private Icon getIcon(Shape shape, final boolean fill,
        final boolean outline) {
        final int width = shape.getBounds().width;
        final int height = shape.getBounds().height;
        final GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath(shape);
        return new Icon() {
            public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                path.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y));
                if (fill) {
                    g2.fill(path);
                }
                if (outline) {
                    g2.draw(path);
                }
                path.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-x, -y));
            }

            public int getIconWidth() {
                return width;
            }

            public int getIconHeight() {
                return height;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MinMaxCategoryPlotTest demo = new MinMaxCategoryPlotTest("Rating Interval");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class MyMinMaxCategoryRenderer extends MinMaxCategoryRenderer {

        @Override
        public void drawItem(Graphics2D g2, CategoryItemRendererState state,
            Rectangle2D dataArea, CategoryPlot plot, CategoryAxis domainAxis,
            ValueAxis rangeAxis, CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column,
            int pass) {
            super.drawItem(g2, state, dataArea, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, row, column, pass);

            //Draw label
            if (dataset.getRowCount() - 1 == row) { //last row

                Number value = dataset.getValue(row, column);
                double x1 = domainAxis.getCategoryMiddle(column, getColumnCount(),
                    dataArea, plot.getDomainAxisEdge());
                double y1 = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(value.doubleValue(), dataArea,
                    plot.getRangeAxisEdge());

                g2.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                String name = dataset.getColumnKey(column).toString();
                int width = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(name);

                g2.drawString(name, (int) y1 - width, (int) x1 - 12);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Final complete result for Rating / Confidence Intervals:
[image: Final result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `BoxAndWhiskerRenderer`, examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38394629/230513), use a [`MinMaxCategoryRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/MinMaxCategoryRenderer.html) with `PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL` and a custom `AxisLocation`.

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
MinMaxCategoryRenderer renderer = new MinMaxCategoryRenderer();
plot.setRenderer(renderer);
plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
```

[image]

You can change the `Icon` used like this, or you can create your own icons based on [this approach](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/MinMaxCategoryRenderer.html#line.451).

```
renderer.setObjectIcon(renderer.getMinIcon());
```

Comment: Thank you, the MinMaxCategoryRenderer does the trick. However the last number on the y axis is sitll outside of the frame. And is still don't know how to dsiplay labels above the lines as in my example.

Comment: Use a `CategoryItemLabelGenerator`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13627138/230513); please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows any other problems.

Comment: This works with `IntervalBarRenderer` but not with `MinMaxCategoryRenderer` or `BoxAndWhiskerRenderer`.

Comment: It looks like you'd have to override `drawItem()` or you could try an annotation.

Comment: Thank you it seems that overriding `drawItem()` was the best option. I also fixed the problem where the last tick label was cut off by adding `chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(10, 10, 10, 10));`  which I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16091409/1462906). I updated my code containing the final solution.