# Create forest plot using JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart, forest-plots

Does anyone have an example of how to render a forest plot using JFreeChart (or another Java-based open source charting library, but JFreeChart is preferred due to the integration with Jasper Reports)?

See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_plot for description of the forest plot.

I was thinking about hacking somethign together using a horizontal bar chart where left side of the axis is the categorical value, and right side is the range, but the problem is the data for a forest plot comes in a set of data like: category, min, max.  Such as an odd ratio with a confidence interval that spans between -.1 to 1.2.  The forrest plot would basically be a line drawn between -.1 and 1.2 with a diamond marker directly in the middle (around .55).

If anyone has experience on building this visualization in JFreeChart, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not supported directly in the current release, a reasonable facsimile should be possible. Instead of a bar chart, consider using a [`MinMaxCategoryRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/MinMaxCategoryRenderer.html) having `PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL` and custom icons, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275190/230513). Add a `CategoryMarker` or `CategoryLineAnnotation` with a dashed `Stroke` to the `CategoryPlot` for the centerline; add a `CategoryItemLabelGenerator` to handle the labels.

[image]