# Set highest tick mark value at maximum date on date axis jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I tried subclassing the DateAxis:

```
private class FixDateAxis extends DateAxis {

    @Override
    public Date calculateLowestVisibleTickValue(DateTickUnit unit) {
        return getMinimumDate();
    }

    @Override
    public Date calculateHighestVisibleTickValue(DateTickUnit unit) {
        return getMaximumDate();
    }
}
```

and use it with my plot:

```
axis = new FixDateAxis();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
axis.setDateFormatOverride(formatter);
axis.setFixedAutoRange(5000);
plot.setDomainAxis(axis);
```

Result:

[image]

But I want actually is one more tick value at the end of the x-axis.

Is it possible with JFreeChart? Any pointers will help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JFreeChart tick label cut off*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7851540/230513).

Comment: `setUpperMargin` does not work. It seems like the axis does not show the last tick mark, rather being cut off.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @Forrest did you find the solution for that and I'm facing the same problem at the start point also. The x-axis doesn't show the start point as well.